# nth calls to a function

Tags: java, recursion, dictionary

I can't seem to understand how to implement this function. The prototype is below:

```
public static <K> K nthGet (Map<K,K> m, K k, int n);
```

What it's supposed to do is take a map, m, and return the nth key from that map starting from k. So, if n is 3 then you return m.get(m.get(m.get(k))).

I have a feeling I have to use recursive calls to nthGet to return the final value of the key from n but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Tough one.. but it may help to use mnemonic variable names

Answer (score 4):

You can simply loop n times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    k = m.get(k);
}
return k;
```

If a value is not present in the map as a key, this might return null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion, you should consider first the *base case*, and next the *inductive case*.

The base case here is `n=0`. This is easy: we don't have to lookup in the map, so just `return k`.

The inductive case is just to return `m.get(nthGet(m, k, n-1))` since we do one lookup per call.

Therefore, the code is quite simple:

```
K nthGet (Map<K,K> m, K k, int n) {
    if(n == 0) return k;
    return m.get(nthGet(m, k, n-1));
}
```